# why chaincode in dev mode could not connect to peer while throw Unimplemented desc = unknown service protos.ChaincodeSupport

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc

Fabric code before version v1.1.0-preview is ok ,but 
I download the fabric release version [v1.1.0-preview](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v1.1.0-preview) . I boot the program with dev mode, not docker mode.
orderer、peer、example01 cofiguration is following:

[image: orderer configuration]

[image: peer configuration]

[image: example01 cofiguration]
then, orderer、peer could start normally , but example01 could not start,it seems grpc could not connect success,

[image: error message for example01]

```
GOROOT=/opt/go1.9.2 #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/test/gopath #gosetup
/opt/go1.9.2/bin/go build -i -gcflags "-N -l" -tags nopkcs11 "-ldflags=-linkmode internal" -o /tmp/___example01 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example01 #gosetup
/tmp/___example01 -peer.address 127.0.0.1:7051 #gosetup
2017-12-29 15:14:01.381 CST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
2017-12-29 15:14:01.381 CST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...
2017-12-29 15:14:01.383 CST [shim] func1 -> ERRO 003 Received error from server, ending chaincode stream: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service protos.ChaincodeSupport
Error starting Simple chaincode: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service protos.ChaincodeSupport
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I consider the key code in chaincode.go ,the method chatWithPeer failed, it use chaincode_shim.proto the grpc service ,it Failed.

```
// Interface that provides support to chaincode execution. ChaincodeContext
// provides the context necessary for the server to respond appropriately.
service ChaincodeSupport {

    rpc Register(stream ChaincodeMessage) returns (stream ChaincodeMessage) {}


}
```

So, why it throw `Unimplemented desc = unknown service protos.ChaincodeSupport`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong port. In v1.1, we switched to use port 7052.
In v1.0 it's 7051.